# ¿Cómo puedo tener el mismo tamaño de las imagenes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo una galería de imágenes con image-card de bootstrap, pero no todas las imagenes son del mismo tamaño, entonces algunas se ven mas grandes que otras, como hago para que la imagen quede al mismo tamaño aunque la imagen sea mas grande en resolución?

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Cómo queda:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cómo me gustaría:** (Este ejemplo es de la vista de galeria de Notion)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces la imagen se adapta al pequeño cuadro sin importar su tamaño.

¿Es alguna propiedad del CSS o es de bootstrap? ¿Cómo puedo profundizar del tema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las imágenes principales en Bootstrap tienen solamente `width: 100%`. Las demás declaraciones están en el propio HTML, en línea, o en la misma etiqueta img: (`width="500px" height="500px"`).

Para agregarle más estilos, se puede hacer una clase extra o usar la misma de Bootstrap y darle más estilos:

La siguiente es para que se adapte en un cuadro, centrando y recortando el excedente, usando `object-fit: cover`.

También en este ejemplo uso variable, para que cambien la medida (18rem) en un solo lugar. Esto es normal y la mejor forma de escribir CSS.

A `.card-img-top` le puse un ancho de 100% pero el máximo de la variable `--max`.

Pero solo debe tener un `height` específico (ni auto ni max ni min ni nada). En este caso tiene la misma medida del ancho, para que sea cuadrado. Pero se puede cambiar a uno más alto: por ejemplo `height: 20rem` o con una nueva variable.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}

:root {
--max: 18rem
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-height: 100%
}

.card {
width: var(--max)
}

.card-img-top {
width: 100%;
max-width: var(--max);
height: calc(var(--max));
object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello, World!
    </h1>
    
    <div class="card"> 
        
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-OAYrbpcO1mw335U2326RvWF6ySq_zny" alt="Card image cap"> 
        
        <div class="card-body">
            
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5> 
            
            <p class="card-text">Ésta imágen es horizontal</p> 
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
            
        </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"> 
        
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1-hXGeXs5KfDj_nO95mNJKyNdHW4npJPA" alt="Card image cap"> 
        
        <div class="card-body">
            
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5> 
            
            <p class="card-text">Ésta imágen es vertical</p> 
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
            
        </div> 
    </div>
    
    
</body>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora entiendo mejor!

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo de arriba te debe de servir, como te dice, debes usar `object-fit: cover;` para que la imagen se adapte al cuadro. Esta propiedad recortara la imagen para adaptarla al cuadro necesario. Si necesitas que la imagen rellene el cuadro puedes usar `object-fit: fill`